# Units in [Location1].DistanceTo[Location2]

Tags: c#, android, geolocation

I have been trying to find out what unit the `.DistanceTo` gives me.

The articles related so far mention geounits, but no further explanation

Using an elapsed time, and 2 locations I am calculating the speed my device is going.

I'm not sure how to get the result from `distance=Location1.DistanceTo(Location2);` in Km, or any other METRIC unit. I have to use metric for my app.

Any help solving this or guiding me toward the solution would be helpful.

Comment: According to the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) the method returns the distance in metres. Have you tried testing it between two locations that you know the distance between to see if the values returned do seem like metres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) the method returns the distance in metres.

> Returns the approximate distance in ***meters*** between this location and
>   the given location.

So to get it in kilometres, just divide the result by 1000:

```
float distanceInMetres = Location1.DistanceTo(Location2);
float distanceInKilometres = distanceInMetres / 1000;
```

Comment: Ty, I never found that bit of info in-line. My rep is to low to vote up the answer, but I do so in spirit

Comment: @bbbwex Glad it could help. If it does answer your question, you should still be able to mark it as the "correct answer" regardless of your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public double CalculationByDistance(GeoPoint StartP, GeoPoint EndP) {
int Radius=6371;//radius of earth in Km         
double lat1 = StartP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double lat2 = EndP.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double lon1 = StartP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double lon2 = EndP.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
double valueResult= Radius*c;
double km=valueResult/1;
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
kmInDec =  Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
meter=valueResult%1000;
meterInDec= Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
Log.i("Radius Value",""+valueResult+"   KM  "+kmInDec+" Meter   "+meterInDec);

return Radius * c;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah that's the long way around using the haversine formula, and not an answer to my question. Nice try